# When creating a class array its members are still not instantiated

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, initialization, nullreferenceexception

Sorry for the stupid question!

Why do I get a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

```
public class myTestClass
{
    public string testString;
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public myTestClass[] testedClassObject;

    private void Start()
    {
        testedClassObject = new myTestClass[2];
        testedClassObject[0].testString = "test";  // --> Error
    }
}
```

I guess I need a constructor for the string in my class, but how should that look like?

Comment: You instantiate only the array, and you need to instantiate also the object itself.

testedClassObject = new myTestClass[2];
testedClassObject[0] = new myTestClass();

Comment: Basically `testedClassObject[0]` has not been set.

Comment: As a tip: public fields are rarely a good idea, and it is usually a good idea to follow .NET naming conventions; I would expect, therefore, `public class MyTestClass`, `public string TestString {get;set;}` and `public MyTestClass[] TestedClassObject {get;set;}` (or perhaps even: `public List<MyTestClass> TestedClassObject {get;} = new List<MyTestClass>();`. None of these things impact the answer, so I'm just offering this as a side commentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an array, the contents are wiped to zero, which for references means: all the references are `null` (creating an array or references does not also create objects for each element in the array). As such, you need to *explicitly create objects* for the contents. For example:

```cs
testedClassObject = new myTestClass[2];
testedClassObject[0] = new myTestClass { testString = "test" };
```

or perhaps more conveniently:

```cs
testedClassObject = new [] {
    new myTestClass { testString = "test" },
    // etc  
};
```

which performs the array and contents initialization at the same time (and infers the length for you).